# Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers + Subclipse + JavaHL on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: eclipse, macos, subclipse, javahl

I want to use the Eclipse plugin Subclipse on Snow Leopard.
I installed Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers (Helios Service Release 1).

I should mention that the subversion server ist SSL protected, I have to use a personal certificate (p12 file).

I tell the system where to find the certificate file in

```
/Users/<USERNAME>/.subversion/servers
```

with this lines:

```
[groups]
servername = 999.999.99.99
...
[servername]
ssl-client-cert-file = /Users/<USERNAME>/Desktop/<CERTIFICATE>
```

Using SVN in the command line this works.

So my first try was to use the Subclipse plugin offered by subclipse.tigris.org within Eclipse's "Install new software" dialogue. This offers me the Subclipse 1.0.0.
It ended with this error in Eclipse's console view when trying to connect to the SVN repository:

```
svn: PROPFIND request failed on '/blahblahblahrepositorydirectory'
svn: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

I thought it might be a good idea to use a newer SVN version + JavaHL (Snow Leopard's preinstalled SVN is 1.0) but according to http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-5ccce53a67ca6c3965de863ae91e2642eab537de one needs at least SVN/JavaHL Version 1.4.x from openCollabNet. But 1.4.x is not available there for Mac OS X 10.6. You get only 1.6 there.
So I took the 1.6 and expected Ecipse's "Install new software" dialogue to offer me a newer version of Subclipse but it still offers the 1.0.0. And actually this combination doesn't work, still getting errors when trying to connect with SVN...

What can I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you get Subclipse to begin with that you would have the 1.0 version?  Current Subclipse is 1.6.x and has been out for nearly 2 years.

Just specify the update site URL for Subclipse 1.6.x and install it.  Or use the Eclipse Marketplace client to do so.

Comment: I installed "Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers" from the Eclipse.org download page and added http://subclipse.tigris.org/update as new repository in the Help/Install new software dialogue. This brought me only Subclipse 1.0.0.

Comment: Silly me... I took the Update Site URL from an external website which was outdated... :-/ Now with the correct URL it works like a charme. :-)